# Komparativ : Infinitiv plus zu

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context

Warum braucht man `zu` in dem folgenden Satz ?

> In einem Notfall werden Menschen lieber ihrer Familie
> beistehen, als Fremde *zu* unterstützen.

`werden ... beistehen` steht im Hauptsatz als Futurform. Warum wird nicht ebenso gut `unterstützen` ohne `zu` im Nebensatz bzw im Komparativ benutzt, wo der Auxiliar `werden`, schon im Hauptsatz, wird nicht wiederholt doch implizit gemeint ? Sozusagen

> ... werden Menschen lieber ihrer Familie
> beistehen, als [werden sie] Fremde unterstützen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genaugenommen ist die Form mit "zu" der Infinitiv (Präsens Indikativ Aktiv). Das ist ähnlich dem "to" in Englisch: der Infinitiv ist zB nicht "run" sondern "*to* run" und analog dazu ist der Indikativ im Deutschen nicht "laufen" sondern "*zu* laufen".

Das "zu" kann wegfallen nach: sollen, wollen, können, mögen, müssen, dürfen und lassen:

> Ich lasse fallen.

> Du kannst lesen.

Dagegen:

> Ich verhindere zu fallen.

> Du vermagst zu lesen.

"zu + *Infinitiv*" tritt in einer solchen Konstruktion an die Stelle eines Akkusativobjekts und ist vergleichbar mit der lateinischen Form des ACI (accusativus cum infinitivus). Das wird insbesondere klar, wenn man ein verdeutlichendes "es" einfügt. Dieses "es" ist dann ein Akkusativobjekt, das durch den Infinitiv näher bestimmt wird:

> Ich verhindere es, zu fallen.

Wen oder was verhindere ich? Es! Was ist "es"? Zu fallen!

Als Paralipomenon: es gibt eine (alte) Grammatik-Merkregel, die darauf Bezug nimmt:

> Wer "brauchen" ohne "zu" gebraucht, braucht "brauchen" nicht zu gebrauchen.